# Build search box searching with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I would like to build an easy search box in my Notes.Application for searching through my notes. I am looking in this website, Ember form and Google and there are not that many solutions. I found just two and they don't fit in my App frowning. The problem is that I don't have a general idea how to do it.

Here is my app:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">  
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="bar">
      {{input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Where is my bookmark??" value=search action="query"}}

        <div class="bar-buttons">
          <button {{action "addNote"}}> NEW </button>
          <button> HOME </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4 class="all-notes">All Notes {{length}}</h4>
          {{#each item in model}}
            <li>
              {{#link-to 'note' item}} {{item.title}} {{/link-to}}
            </li>
          {{/each}}
      </aside>
      {{outlet}}
    </div> 
</script>
```

Controller:

```
Notes.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ({
search: '',

actions:{
    query: function() {
      // the current value of the text field
      var query = this.get('search');
    },

    addNote: function () {
        this.transitionToRoute('main');
    }
}
});
```

Model:

```
    Notes.Note = DS.Model.extend ({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
    });

    Notes.Note.FIXTURES = [ 
    { 
    id: 1, 
    title:'hello world', 
    body: 'ciao ciao ciao ciao', 
    url: '' 
    }, 
    { 
    id: 2, 
    title: 'javascript frameworks',
    body: 'Backbone.js, Ember.js, Knockout.js', 
    url: '...'
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     title: 'Find a job in Berlin',
     body: 'Monster, beralinstartupjobs.com',
     url: '...'
    }
    ];
```

But anyway this is still hard-coded data, later will be just notes added dynamically from the user.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this overriding the `arrangedContent` property of `IndexController`:

```
Notes.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ({
    search: '',    
    titleFilter: null,
    actions:{
        query: function() {
            // the current value of the text field
            var query = this.get('search');
            this.set('titleFilter', query);
        },
        addNote: function () {
            this.transitionToRoute('main');
        }
    },
    arrangedContent: function() {
        var search = this.get('search');
        if (!search) { return this.get('content') }

        return this.get('content').filter(function(note) {            
            return note.get('title').indexOf(search) != -1;
        })
    }.property('content', 'titleFilter')
});
```

And in your template use `{{#each item in arrangedContent}}`

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/v966z/

Comment: Perfect! Is working good! Can please explain me what you did here? More specific I don't understand when you set titleFilter to query, what is 'content', what is arrangedContent and what you do in details in this function.  thank you very much

Comment: `content` is where all data loaded stay, so we cannot change it directlly because we can lost the data, when filtering. So `ArrayController` provide a `arrangedContent` property where we can arrange that content, like pagination, ordering, filtering etc. Because you just want to filter the data when the user press Enter in the input field, arrangedContent observes the content and titleFilter, so when the query action be triggered we set the titleFilter property, this will change the arrangedContent, and because the template is observing it, the update is automatic.

Comment: Other important thing is, the use of content in property('content', 'titleFilter'), because when you add a new item in the `content` the filter will be updated, and if it match with the titleFilter, it will appear in the filtered list.

Comment: Amazing! What I found, indexOf is case sensitive. You can use myVariable.toLowerCase() on both variables before comparing them :)