# Trying to create a search engine using Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js

Hello I am new to developing with Ember.JS and I am having trouble understanding how to develop a query driven search engine with the library.

Could anyone either point me to an example of how to do this or provide some code I could use in my open source project I am developing with the Ember platform?

I would like the user to be able to type in a query in a textbox and then have the results display.

Thank You,
Eric

Answer (score 1):

For text-searching your own site, or a full blown search engine?

If the former, Ember Sherpa has code for an example app here: http://embersherpa.com/articles/search-example/.

There's also an answer with a JSFiddle you can play around with for someone asking a similar question here: [Build search box searching with Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767733/build-search-box-searching-with-ember-js)